# Отложить загрузку <script>,что б не тормозил сайт в пузомерке!

Tags: javascript

всем привет! есть скрипт вставленный в хедере перед тегом ,который надо отложить,или что то с ним сделать,что б он не тормозил сайт в пузомерке! спасибо!

Comment: Вы можете обернуть скрипт в функцию и поставить timeout запуска.

Answer (score 0):

Предположим, вот ваш скрипт:

```
var x = window.confirm("Are you a robot?");
if(x) {
    window.alert("Wow! A real robot! Cool!");
}
```

Помещаете его в функцию

```
function wow(){
    var x = window.confirm("Are you a robot?");
    if(x) {
        window.alert("Wow! A real robot! Cool!");
    }
}
```

И ставите таймаут на 1 секунду (1000 мс):

```
setTimeout(wow, 1000);
```

Таймаут запустит функцию асинхронно, то есть, не последовательно и не тормозя загрузку всего остального.